# Minimize multivariable function

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, surface

I have two quadric surfaces in 3-dimensional space.

- circular hyperboloid of one sheet

  - described by xt, yt, zt, rt
- circular paraboloid

  - described by xs, ys, zs, rs

I would like to minimize the distance between the two objects. Function `distance()` takes 4 variables - alpha, beta, zt and zs. The goal is to find such values of these 4 variables that the function returns the minimal possible value.

Consider the code below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

A = 1; B = 1; C = 1; D = 1; Z = 0;

def distance(alpha,beta,zt,zs):
    """distance between points in 2 quadric surfaces in 3D space"""
    rt = (A/B) * np.sqrt(B**2 + (zt-C)**2)
    xt = rt * np.cos(alpha)
    yt = rt * np.sin(alpha)

    rs = D * np.sqrt(zs-Z)
    xs = rs * np.cos(beta)
    ys = rs * np.sin(beta)

    return (xt-xs)**2 + (yt-ys)**2 + (zt-zs)**2

x0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
res = minimize(distance,
               x0,
               method='nelder-mead')
```

The code gives me the following error.

> TypeError: distance() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'beta',
>   'zt', and 'zs'

All [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead) I have found uses only univariate (one variable) functions (like the Rosenbrock function) despite it saying it minimizes "multivariate scalar functions".

How do I make my code find the optimal values for the 4 parameters to minimize the value of a function?

Comment: The documentation explains how to pass the extra arguments of the objective function in `args`, have you tried? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Right now, the program cannot infer by itself what values of `beta`, `zt`, and `zs` to use when calling the function `distance`, henece the error.

Comment: I don't understand how to use the `args` parameter. I'm quite new with Python and there seems to be no example. Could you help me find out the correct value given the arguments `alpha`, `beta`, `zt` and `zs`?

Comment: By the way I have no idea if `x0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])` works. I just made the numbers up. How do I know what are the reasonable "initial guesses"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to vary all four arguments.  You pass their initial values as `x0`, a 4 element array.  That's what `minimize` will pass to `distance`.  Here's a change to `distance` that should work with that:

```
def distance(x):
    """distance between points in 2 quadric surfaces in 3D space"""
    alpha,beta,zt,zs = x    # unpack x into these 4 variables
    rt = (A/B) * np.sqrt(B**2 + (zt-C)**2)
    xt = rt * np.cos(alpha)
    yt = rt * np.sin(alpha)

    rs = D * np.sqrt(zs-Z)
    xs = rs * np.cos(beta)
    ys = rs * np.sin(beta)

    return (xt-xs)**2 + (yt-ys)**2 + (zt-zs)**2
```

The `args` suggestion would vary `alpha` and hold the other 3 constant.  That doesn't sound like what you want. You already use `A`, `B`, `C` as global constants.

```
1115:~/mypy$ python3 stack55751317.py 
 final_simplex: (array([[-1.21456543, -1.21455458,  0.99997997,  0.99997757],
       [-1.21457508, -1.21458998,  0.9999941 ,  1.00000714],
       [-1.21461728, -1.21460427,  1.00002695,  1.00001266],
       [-1.21456081, -1.2145312 ,  0.99996329,  0.99996864],
       [-1.2146315 , -1.21462741,  1.00002628,  1.00004968]]), array([2.49380001e-10, 4.04824635e-10, 4.13486388e-10, 1.15131206e-09,
       1.18130671e-09]))
           fun: 2.4938000073954824e-10
       message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
          nfev: 295
           nit: 172
        status: 0
       success: True
             x: array([-1.21456543, -1.21455458,  0.99997997,  0.99997757])
```

`x` looks like the result, which you can access with `res['x']`.

Most of the items in this `res` dictionary are explained at:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult

`final_simplex` is a special output for this minimization method.

Comment: The full `res` includes an `x`.  `res['x']`

Comment: So for `alpha=-1.21456543`, `beta=-1.21455457`, `zt=0.99997997` and `zs=0.99997757` the function `distance()` has the minimal possible value equal to `2.4938000073954824e-10`?

Comment: @Slazer Indeed, it has. So I think this might be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = minimize(distance,
           x0[0],
           args=(*x0[1:],),
           method='nelder-mead')
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: This only gives me `[0.00025]` after `print(res.x)` and `print(res.fun)` gives `2.0`. That is incorrect because for `alpha`, `beta`, `zt`, `zs` equal to `[-1.21456543, -1.21455458,  0.99997997,  0.99997757]` the function value is `2.4938000073954824e-10` which is way less.